# Can't get JSON POST response

Tags: c#, post, pocket

I have this code:

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request");
        request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; ;
        request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "{\"consumer_key\":\"keyIsHere\",\"redirect_uri\":\"pickpocket:authorizationFinished\"}";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
```

It returns `code=12345456787blahblah` instead of the JSON response: `{"code":"12345456787blahblah"}` and I can't figure out why. I got the POST request/response code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) and the correct request data from the [Pocket API](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `X-Accept` header:

```
request.Headers["X-Accept"] = "application/json";
```

From the API docs: "The X-Accept header indicates the format you would like to receive the response, the Pocket Authentication API supports two formats: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded (DEFAULT)` and `application/json"`

Comment: Great! Is working now, thanks! I thought it may be related to the X-Accept but I had no idea how to add it.